# ITest with different browser version via webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

I'm starting to write a test scenario with selenium web driver and test it via different firefox and IE versions. So, I downloaded GeckoDriver and selenium webdriver itself.
The question is, what version of selenium webdriver, firefoxdriver (gecko driver) and IE driver in order to test my scenario in different browser versions? 
for example firefox since version 35 and IE since version 7.

Is there any references to see which firefox version works with which gecko driver and webdriver versions?

Comment: You better go for a online browser service like browserstack.com or saucelabs for this. Firefox version 35 is quite old.

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani  that was an example, think I'm going to test since FF 47 (or just 3 lastet version of FF) , what should I do then?

Answer (score 0):

this will helps you
https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities

better way is to check change log in http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

exp: for gecko https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/blob/release/CHANGES.md
and webdriver https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG